# React - How do i disable scrolling after rendering?

Tags: react-native, properties, scrollview

I want to control the scrolling direction: disable to swipe left, enable to swipe right with scrollView.

I see the prop named: `scrollEnabled` , but it must be declare at the beginning.
How do i disable scrolling whenever i want?

This question is related to changing prop.
In iOS, i can control the scrolling behaviour easily.

Comment: Just update a state value e.g. `this.setState({ shouldScroll: false })` then use that in the `ScrollView`. For example, you might want to disable outer scroll when an inner element is being interacted with. You'd fire the state change on some event from the inner component.

Comment: @G0dsquad the question is how do i disable `ScrollView` after it rendered. Is there method or any particular way to do it?